# Extending a service-per-pod to multiple ports in metacontroller (kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I have created a service-per-pod for statefulset, and it's working for a single port (80/tcp). However, I need to use it for multiple ports (e.g., 80/tcp, 30000/udp, etc.).

How can I extend this to multiple ports in service-per-pod
[Metacontroller](https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller/tree/master/examples/service-per-pod)?

[sync-service-per-pod.jsonnet - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvNXX.png)

Comment: Did you try something like https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller/blob/master/examples/service-per-pod/my-statefulset.yaml#L21 in your annotation?

Comment: No, But needed jsonnet based example for multiple ports in metacontroller https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvNXX.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [service-per-pod](https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller/tree/master/examples/service-per-pod) sample actually shows you how to do this in [manifest/sync-service-per-pod.jsonnet](https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller/blob/master/examples/service-per-pod/manifest/sync-service-per-pod.jsonnet).

The `service-per-pod-ports` annotation allows you to specify a comma-delimited set of ports which will be exposed by the generated Service:

```
service-per-pod-ports: "80:80,8080:8080"
```

Then in `sync-service-per-pod.jsonnet`:

Get the ports

```
local ports = statefulset.metadata.annotations["service-per-pod-ports"]
```

And then loop through them creating multiple `ports` in the Service spec:

```
   ports: [
      {
        local parts = std.split(portnums, ":"),
        name: "port-" + std.parseInt(parts[0]),
        port: std.parseInt(parts[0]),
        targetPort: std.parseInt(parts[1]),
      }
      for portnums in std.split(ports, ",")
    ]
```

Note the `for portnums in std.split(ports, ",")` iterates over the `ports` set above.

Looks like you are trying to do something a bit more dynamic, so you could so something like:

```
for index in std.range(1,N)
```

where N is is the maximum value of index.

Comment: How to pass combination of Protocol like, 80:8080/tcp and 81:8080/udp ?